# PostgreSQL SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column 'minute' does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the below query and I am getting the following error:

> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column 'minute' does not exist

However I am not referencing any field called `minute`.

```
SELECT customer_id,
MAX(created_at) last_order_date,
MAX(created_at) + ((SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM MAX(created_at)-MIN(created_at)) 
FROM (SELECT customer_id, created_at
FROM (SELECT customer_id, created_at, rank() over (partition by customer_id order by created_at desc) lasttwo
FROM orders) sub
WHERE sub.lasttwo <= 2
AND SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(created_at),MAX(created_at))) > 2) s2) ::text||' minute')::INTERVAL AS nextdate,
(SELECT AVG(total_price - total_tax) 
FROM (SELECT customer_id, created_at, total_price, total_tax
FROM (SELECT customer_id, created_at, total_price, total_tax, rank() over (partition by customer_id order by created_at desc) lasttwo
FROM orders) sub
WHERE sub.lasttwo <= 2
AND SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(created_at),MAX(created_at))) > 2) s2) nextval 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Comment: This is not Postgres syntax:  `DATEDIFF(MINUTE,MIN(created_at),MAX(created_at))`.  Why are you using SQL Server syntax in a Postgres query?

Comment: First figure out which dbms you are using.  Then find out what date functions are available for the dbms you are using.  Using other dbms function on another dbms, then asking why it doesn't work is probably not a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to use `EXTRACT` rather than `DATEDIFF`

```
SELECT customer_id,
MAX(created_at) last_order_date,
MAX(created_at) + ((SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM MAX(created_at)-MIN(created_at)) 
FROM (SELECT customer_id, created_at
FROM (SELECT customer_id, created_at, rank() over (partition by customer_id order by created_at desc) lasttwo
FROM orders) sub
WHERE sub.lasttwo <= 2
AND SUM(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM MAX(created_at)-MIN(created_at))) > 2) s2) ::text||' minute')::INTERVAL AS nextdate,
(SELECT AVG(total_price - total_tax) 
FROM (SELECT customer_id, created_at, total_price, total_tax
FROM (SELECT customer_id, created_at, total_price, total_tax, rank() over (partition by customer_id order by created_at desc) lasttwo
FROM orders) sub
WHERE sub.lasttwo <= 2
AND SUM(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM MAX(created_at)-MIN(created_at))) > 2) s2) nextval  
FROM orders 
GROUP BY customer_id
```